# IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds en python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

ALguna idea de por que al momento de realizar el siguiente ciclo aparece este error?:

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
tabla = pd.json_normalize(data)
total = tabla['total'][0]
key = tabla['key'][0]
id = tabla['id'][0]
salida = pd.json_normalize(tabla['histories'][0])

result = {}
inicia = 0

while inicia < total:
    created = salida.iloc[inicia,1]
    df = pd.json_normalize(salida['items'][inicia]).assign(creacion=created,key=key,id = id)
    result[inicia] = df
    inicia = inicia + 1


return result
```

creo que se debe al indice que estoy pasando en iloc, pero no logro resolver como corregir este problema.

alguna idea?

Comment: Línea del error

Comment: created = salida.iloc[inicia,1]

Comment: tamaño de tu dataframe?, si es posible colócalo en la pregunta

Comment: es variable, ya que obtengo los datos desde una api rest, creo que mi error ocurre cuando no encuentra valores para poder generar el data frame, alguna idea de como modificar el codigo para que continue sin detenerse

Comment: Bueno mételo en un `try/except`

Comment: claro, verás estoy iniciando con python y pandas, que instrucción debería poner en except para que mi codigo omita la acción y pase al siguiente valor?

Comment: `except: pass` o si quieres ver el valor de las variables pones un `print()`, si solo quieres omitir el `pass` esta bien

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente el problema radicaba en que la API que  estoy consultado tiene un máximo de 100 resultados por página máximo, además que puediera devolver o no datos el metodo que estoy utilizando, en fin el problema esta detectado y gracias a @Christian por su orientación en el uso de `try/except` para poder realizar las validaciones necesarias! a seguir aprendiendo!